# How to create Profile when signup new user with Parse.com REST API

Tags: rest, parse-platform

When I use the signup endpoint parse REST api to create new user, I would like to create a profile for this user in 1 call. I have a pointer relation to profile in User table. Is this possible? My current workaround is after user created successfully, then I do another call to create profile, then I update the pointer link to User table, so that's 3 call total. I would like to do 1.

Thanks.

```
curl -X POST \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: xxx" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: xxx" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{"username":"cooldude6","password":"p_n7!-e8","phone":"415-392-0202"}' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/users
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is - to use **CloudCode** module. Take a look on this functions **[beforeSave/afterSave/...](https://www.parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#functions-onsave)**. Create Profile/other Objects & Save.